# get each element from array at a time with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, callback

I need to get all elements from array but one at a time and only to show up after something had been done with previous element. For example:

```
var elems = ['Apple','Orange','Banana'],
        i = 0;

elems.forEach(function(e){
     elems[i++].fadeIn(200, arguments.callee); // here I need some kind of callback function to process first element, and only when that's finished, another element should fadeIn. 
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function

```
var elems = ['Apple','Orange','Banana'],
        i = 0;

function (recursive(elem) {
     $(elem).fadeIn(200, function() {
         recursive(elems[++i]);
     });
})(elems[0]);
```

or just `delay()`

```
var elems = ['Apple','Orange','Banana'],
        i = 0;

$.each(elems, function(i, e){
     e.delay(i*speed).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
$(function(){
var myArray = ['Apple','Orange','Banana'];
    var i=0;
$.each(myArray, function(index, value){
     elems[i++].fadeIn(200, arguments.callee); // here I need some 
});
});
```